# Users overwrites LSB_ESUB_METHOD

Tags: linux, job-control, lsf

Our LSF has set to `LSB_ESUB_METHOD="esub.default"`. Some of the users, found this and setting as `LSB_ESUB_METHOD=""`, which leads to bypassing restriction enabled in esub.default

Can overwriting this variable restricted? or any other alternative

Comment: What's LSF? Some context might be helpful

Comment: LSF is Load sharing facility, used for job distribution on a computer culster

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_LSF this?

Comment: Yes, We have enforced some restrictions with esub as above, so before submitting it will check if that command has such requirements